Shinyapp to download slides with a map
Here is a quick example of a shiny app that allows the user to select data to display on a map and to download slides containing this map. It works locally but not when deployed. It seems related to PhantomJS but i can't figure out if there is a solution? Or maybe a workaround to the use of mapshot?
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(officer)
library(shiny)
library(mapview)
library(webshot)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(RSelenium)




temp_folder <- tempfile()

onStop(function() {
  cat("Removing Temporary Files and Folders\n")
  unlink(temp_folder, recursive=TRUE)
})

dir.create(temp_folder)

stations_sf <- read.csv('https://assets.datacamp.com/production/course_6355/datasets/stations_data.csv') %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude")) %>% 
  st_sf(crs = 4326)

GeneratePowerpoint<-function(temp_folder,station){
  
  vwidth<-1350
  vheight<-880
  
  map<-leaflet(data = stations_sf,options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.PositronNoLabels) %>% 
    addMarkers()

  tempmap<-file.path(temp_folder,'Map.png')
  
  file.copy(mapshot(map,file=file.path(temp_folder,'Map.png'),vwidth = vwidth, vheight = vheight),tempmap, overwrite=TRUE)
  
  example_pptx <- system.file(package = "officer", "doc_examples/example.pptx")
  
  my_pres<-read_pptx(example_pptx) %>% 
    add_slide(layout = "Image avec légende", master = "My Theme") %>%    
    ph_with(value = external_img(tempmap), location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "Espace réservé pour une image  2"))
  
  return(my_pres)
  
}



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(85vh - 80px) !important;}"),
  ),
  
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Maps on slides"),
              div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:center; width: 150px;",
                  pickerInput('Station',
                              "Choose stations()",
                              unique(stations_sf$station),
                              selected=unique(stations_sf$station),
                              multiple=TRUE)),
              div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:center; width: 150px;",downloadButton("downloadSlides", "Download slides")),
              leafletOutput("map")
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  if (is.null(suppressMessages(webshot:::find_phantom()))) { webshot::install_phantomjs() }
  

  output$downloadSlides <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {  
      "Slides.pptx"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      
      example_pp<-GeneratePowerpoint(temp_folder,station())
      
      print(example_pp, target = file)
    }
  )
  
  station<-reactive({
    stations_sf %>% dplyr::filter(station %in% input$Station)
  })
  
  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet(data = station(),options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.PositronNoLabels) %>% 
      addMarkers() 
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

